# How delete item and itemWidget correctly from QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

i dont understand how correctly delete item and itemWidget from QListWidget.
I should at first delete itemWidget, then item

```
lstWgt->removeItemWidget(item);
delete item;
```

Or i can

```
auto *pItem = lstWgt->takeItem(2);
delete item;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the Qt documentation and by my Qt 4&5 experience, both should be correct, however your last `delete` should be the Pointer you get returned by `takeItem` so `delete pItem` instead of `delete item` in your second snippet.